# displaying an individual integer in webix

Tags: javascript, webix

I want to display a single number (that would change, that's why I'm not hard coding it) from am object. This, however, doesn't display anything.

```
var game_data = {
    amount:     1,
    yes_left:   3,
    nos_left:   1
};

var game_panel = {
    view: "form", id:"game_panel", 
    rows:[
        {cols:[
            {
                template:'<span class="main_title">Money: $#amount#.00 </span>',
                data:{amount:game_data.amount},align:"center"
            },
        }
    ]
};
```

I've also tried returning it as a variable:

```
template: function(game_data) {return '<span class="main_title">Money: ' + game_data.amount + '.00 </span>'}
```

Any ideas how to get that to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you are using is correct. You can check the the next working snippet http://webix.com/snippet/82566e82

If you plan to update this number dynamically, it will be better to use a bit different syntax

```
id:"t1", 
template:'<span class="main_title">Money: $#amount#.00 </span>',
data: game_data, align:"center"
```

and for number updating, be sure to call template.refresh, as template doesn't track data changes automatically.

```
game_data.amount += 2;
$$("t1").refresh();
```

http://webix.com/snippet/e3b0450d